# Do you perform any validation on arguments to methods of Javascript API wrappers you develop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, validation, wrapper

When I develop API wrappers I always find myself bouncing between the two ends:

- performing no validation at all because API server performs it;
- performing validation to

  - avoid bad requests without having to call the API server
  - avoid data inconsistencies due to type casting

Did you decide? If so, what kind of validation you prefer? Do you throw errors or pass them to the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should validate inputs in both places.  Pushing validation off to just the server hurts the responsiveness of your application.  Anytime you can avoid a server request in favor of client side code is a win in my book, it's faster on the client and less load on your server.  Unfortunately this means you duplicate validation logic on both ends, but that is acceptable in my book.